# XPages control is not displaying properly

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

Running my XPages application on RedHat Enterprise Linux Server 6.5 i notice problem with my control, for example i am unable to open and close section control also the Rich Text control(CKEditor) is display like a textbox. see image below:
[image]

can anyone tell me what is wrong or what i need to fix the problem

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache to make sure that all css and js resources are reloaded? Do you see any 404s in the browser network inspector?

Comment: no i did not see any 404s on browser

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache to make sure that all css and js resources are reloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about RedHat to know if there could be OS-specific issues.

Is the database set to compile to a specific (older) version of Domino? If so, it could be looking for a specific release's Dojo components. A newly-installed server will only have the latest Dojo version, not historical versions, which can explain it looking different on one server and another.

Using Firebug should confirm the Dojo version it's looking for and whether it's failing to find files at a specific location.

Comment: the dojo version is 1.9.7 but i dont get what u mean by "compile to a specific (older) version of Domino"

Comment: In the xsp.properties you can define "Compile this application to run on". That will force it to use Dojo versions as well as property settings of a specific Domino release, I believe.

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with the dojo version, how to i compile with an older version of Dojo?

Comment: or beter still how do i install dojo version 1.9.7 on server.

Comment: 1.9.7 is 9.0.1 FP5, see https://wiki.openntf.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5832717. To get 1.9.7, you need to upgrade the server to 9.0.1 FP5. Putting it on manually is inadvisable, you're likely to be on your own troubleshooting any unusual behaviour. I'm not sure you can compile to a specific fix pack level, but compiling to e.g. 9.0 or 8.5.3 will be done with the setting I mentioned in xsp.properties (accessible under Application Configuration > Xsp Properties in Domino Designer.